# (Android Studio)Create textview based on the number of times a button is clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, button, textview

So what i want to do is to create a textView and editText based on the number of times a button is clicked. the format is something like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyCHU.png)

What i want to do here is that whenever the button "CLICK" is clicked a new PlainText and Textview should be added. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll have to do this programmatically, but how you exactly do it all depends on how your XML layout is defined. I would suggest something like this...

```
public void addStuff(LinearLayout parentLayout){
        LinearLayout master = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        master.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        master.setWeightSum(2f);
        master.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
        editText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        master.addView(textView);
        master.addView(editText);
        parentLayout.addView(master);
    }
```

Your parentLayout you need to get based on your layout. The 1f's in the LayoutParams represent layout_weights. The 2f of master is a weight sum. Since you set the master layout to horizontal orientation, the TextView and EditText will end up being on the same line. Since 1f + 1f = 2f, this means that the TextView and EditText will have equal widths on the same line.